# How to pass args and kwargs to setter

Tags: python, setter

```
class Cls:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = *args, **kwargs

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._x = do_thing(args, kwargs)
        pass

obj = Cls(5, 4, a=15, b=20)
```

I want to pass arguments to a setter, but the line `self.x = *args, **kwargs` results in a syntax error. Passing w/o the asterisks means that a tuple and a dictionary is passed into args in the setter, which isn't what I want. I also tried treating x like a function, eg `self.x(*args, **kwargs)`, or `self.x.setter(*args, **kwargs)`, but the getter is called instead, raising an AttributeError because the variable `self._x` does not exist yet.

A workaround I'm using is to have the first two arguments accept a tuple and dictionary instead of *args, **kwargs, but is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Since some of you want more context

The property is an image format (gray, rgb, hsv, etc.) For the setter, I don't require a particular image format to be passed, so I allow any format to be passed to kwargs, which the setter will then convert and save to the variable.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: What `*args, **kwargs` is doing is separating the items and keys in the list and dictionary in a format that is good for passing arguments and keyword arguments to functions. So, basically what you're trying to do is `self._x = argsitem1, argsitem2, kwargsitem1="something", kwargsitem2="somethingelse"`, which is invalid syntax. Also, you can't store both a list and a dictionary in a variable unless you use an array (a list or a tuple, or even a dictionary) to do so.

Comment: A property setter defines what happens when you do `obj.x = whatever`. It doesn't look like you're trying to define what happens when you do `obj.x = whatever`. It looks like you're trying to achieve some other goal, and you've mistakenly decided on a setter as the way to do it. What underlying goal are you trying to achieve by defining this setter?

Comment: "The property is an image format (gray, rgb, hsv, etc.) For the setter, I don't require a particular image format to be passed, so I allow any format to be passed to kwargs, which the setter will then convert and save to the variable." - that doesn't sound like you need `*args` or `**kwargs` for that.

Comment: Properties implement a particular interface, one you can't modify.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass the arguments in a single value, for example a tuple consisting of a tuple of positional arguments and a `dict` of keyword arguments.

```
class Cls:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = *args, **kwargs

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,v):
        self._x = do_thing(*v[0], **v[1])


c = Cls(1, 2, a=3, b=4)
c.x = (5,4), {'a': 15, 'b': 20}
```

The value assigned to `c.x` consists of the same pairs of values stored in the `args` and `kwargs` defined by `__init__`.